# Cannot open database in unit test but db created

Tags: c#, sql-server, unit-testing, .net-core

In unit test I would like to test db CRUD functions in real db environment.

The db is created, but when I call savechanges() I got the exception:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot open database "..." requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user '....'.

Why? The context is the same.

```
services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
                  options.UseSqlServer(string.Format(Configuration["ConnectionString"],
                     Configuration["DbServer"],
                     Configuration["DbName"] + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                     Configuration["DbUserName"],
                     Configuration["DbPassword"])));

public override void SetupDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
  {
     serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<Context>().Database.Migrate();
  }
}
```

Comment: Context is the same, but it’s config differ  the error states that user credentials is invalid.

Comment: Try to debug your unit tests and see what user credentials are used

Comment: Could you help me where I can check the credentials?

The other thing I don't understand, that without Guid like dbname, the credentials are ok. It creates the db, inserts tests data and unit tests run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by moving `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` out of the `AddDbContext` scope.

It seems `AddDbContext` is called multiple times and having it inside of `AddDbContext` causes the connection string to change each time.